# Using Lucene to search documents with punctuation

Tags: java, lucene

I have documents with lines like

**blah blah blah /result1/result2/result3/ blah blah blah**

To index this I am using a WhitespaceAnalyzer, and a regex query to match the literal '/' characters, and the expected values for result1, 2, 3.

This is working as expected.

How would I change this to match lines like?

**blah blah blah /result1 / result2 / result3/ blah blah blah**

To further complicate the problem, the number of results can vary from 1 to 4.

Comment: Could you show the expected query you want to run? A bit unclear, what's the problem here

Comment: The problem is I don't know the expected query ahead of time. I am looking for a generic way to match a set of queries that fit the pattern like above.
I believe if I use a PhraseQuery with the WhitespaceAnalyzer I can match results like the above patterns with spaces between '/'text tokens.
I also believe that I can use a TermQuery to match the no space example.